# Accessing controls in one page from another page

Tags: c#, uwp, projection

I have 2 monitors ( monitor 1 and 2) and 2 pages ( page 1 and 2). I used Projection APIs to display each page in 2 two monitors.

My requirement is to execute the ok button (page 2 ) operation whenever i clicked the ok button in Page 1.

[PLease find the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri8Lx.jpg)

Comment: Hi sumith, welcome to [SO]. I've taken the liberty of removing the tags from your question title. I think you'll find the tag system here on SO more than adequate :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write some user defined events and define an event handler. For example you could write an event for page 2 "OkButtonPressed". Every time this button is pressed the event on page 1 will be raised.

```
public event EventHandler<OkButtonPressedEventArgs> OkButtonPressed;

protected void OnOkButtonPressed()
{
    OkButtonPressedEventArgs args = new OkButtonPressedEventArgs()
    {
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
    };

    OkButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, args);
}

public class OkButtonPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

On Page 1 you can subscribe to the event:

```
OkButtonPressed += MainPage_OkButtonPressed;
```